# How to get user session from Replication event in AEM?

Tags: session, osgi, aem, jcr

I have to get user session who has activated a page in AEM, within Replication Event listener. Using that session, I would instantiate a workflow which inserts some data into tables. Similarly, on deactivation will delete some data in DB tables, if deactivated.

Is it possible to get user session in replication event listener ?
This will help the user to see if any step got failed and I can even add some user participation step and ask certain more data in specific scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think you can get the session but you can get the user data inside handle event by writing below code to get the user details--The user who has triggered the event.

```
handleEvent(Event event)
event.getProperty(WorkflowEvent.USER));
```